# I am getting false as boolean value but the output is always showing me successful instead of unsuccessful. Can anyone tell me whats wrong in this

Tags: java, selenium

```
Boolean EleWNote=this.commonMethods.elementIsVisible(WireNote);

if(EleWNote = true) {
    testStep.log(LogStatus.PASS, "The Element displayed " + wirenote + " successfully");
} else {
    testStep.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "The Element displayed " + wirenote + " not successful");
}
```

This the part of my code where i give the method and in brackets the web element name and i gave the wrong X path to the web element and it should show me that the element displayed wire note is not successful. but it shows successful.

Comment: `if(EleWNote=true)` doesn't this throw at least a warning when compiling?

Comment: `if(EleWNote=true)` should be `if(EleWNote==true)`.  You are accidentally assigning the value in the `if` statement

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
 if(EleWNote=true)
```

to

```
  if(EleWNote==true)
```

or

```
  if(EleWNote)  // this is the recommend way
```

since `EleWNote=true` means to assign `true` to the variable `EleWNote`

Answer (score 0):

You should write EleWNote==true not **EleWNote=true** it will assign value to EleWNote not compare them

check below code

```
if(EleWNote==true)
                {
                    testStep.log(LogStatus.PASS, "The Element displayed " + wirenote + " successfully");
                }
                else
                {
                    testStep.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "The Element displayed " + wirenote + " not successful");
}
```

Comment: Its working now thank you guys i know its a simple mistake at the end but thank you guys for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `EleWNote=true` assings `true` to `EleWNote`, and after it does, the if condition checks weather `EleWNote` is `true`, which is always.

You need to use the comparator operator `==` or `===` (which i recommend) in `if` conditions.

In your case since the variable is `boolean`, you can use  `if(EleWNote)`

My recommended code

```
if(EleWNote)
{
     testStep.log(LogStatus.PASS, "The Element displayed " + wirenote + " successfully");
}
else
{
     testStep.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "The Element displayed " + wirenote + " not successful");
}
```